# Xamarin Forms WebView will not open link which goes to a new tab

Tags: javascript, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

**Edit 3:**
I've found a link it reacts the same way as in our intranet link.
Simple example with this code in xaml. **I think the problem is not JavaScript, its opening a link in a new tab**.:

```
   <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Dokumente zu FA 23124" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10" />
        <WebView x:Name="webBrowser"  Source="https://www.w3schools.com/" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Link in green button on the left works (link opens in same window), Link on the right is not opening (opens in a new tab in chrome):
[image]

we have a Xamarin Forms PCL project and have the requirement to open a third party website (URL for a space in document management system).
I've tried to implement it with Xamarin Forms WebView but with this the dialog will not show the tapped document. The document should be opened in a separate window which is executed by JavaScript.

The examples for creating a hybrid WebView don't fit our requirements because we wouldn't invoke the code by ourselves. Its on the page and should be executed. In a webbrowser on the android device the dialog will be shown.
Even a custom renderer with EnableJavaScript = true was not the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Thanks!

**Edit: Sorry its a bit difficult to describe... here are the GIFS :)**

Window **not** opens in App (Xamarin Webview):
[image: Window not opens in App (Xamarin WebView)]

Window opens in a default browser on Android Device:
[image: Window opens in a default Browser on Android Device]

**Edit2:** The documents open with a link to a custom webviewer of the third party software. They do not open with an App on the device or a PDF reader of the browser.

[image]

Comment: with what u have written its unclear what u have tried so if u can add some code of what u have tried till now would be great

Comment: @kuek3n not sure what means `I've tried to implement it with Xamarin Forms WebView but with this the dialog will not show the tapped document.`, you can provide some code or gif to describe your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! I've attached GIFs to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @kuek3n Maybe you can provide some code that you have tried, because I am not sure what is your problem, guess that you try to load third party website by webview in Xamarin.android?